# BindingAdapter custom getter 2 way data binding

Tags: android, android-databinding

I've created a custom setter that sets the text of an enum into an editText:

```
public enum Gender {
MALE, FEMALE}
```

XML:

```
 <EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    custom:holder="@={user.gender}" />
```

Adapter:

```
@BindingAdapter ("custom:holder")
public static void setHolder(EditText editText, Gender gender) {
    editText.setText(gender.toString());
}
```

From code:

```
binder= DataBindingUtil.bind(getView());
binder.setUser(user);
```

**How can I specify a getter that returns a `Gender` object?**

I tried the following code but it doesn't seem to be the right way.

```
@BindingAdapter ("custom:holder")
public static Gender getHolder(EditText editText) {
    return Gender.valueOf(editText.getText().toString());
}
```

What I want to achieve is that when I call `binder.getUser()`, the Gender will be automatically filled.
Is it possible to do that?

Comment: As far as I know, data binding isn't two way yet

Comment: Guys thank you for your comments but you are not really helping this way

Comment: @Manza you just can't do it. That's all.

Comment: @pskink error?)

Comment: @pskink two-way binding can be done only by Observables. Didn't find any "@=" in [official docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#data_objects)

Comment: @pskink so that is the answer)

Comment: @pskink Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using `EditText` for enum value, I suggest to use `Spinner` with implementations of [`@BindingAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/BindingAdapter.html) and [`@InverseBindingAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/InverseBindingAdapter.html) for bidirection binding.

Your dto:

```
public class User {
    private Gender _gender;
    public Gender getGender() { return _gender; }
    public void setGender(Gender gender) { _gender = gender; }
}

public enum Gender {MALE, FEMALE}
```

Implementation of `@BindingAdapter` for `Spinner`:

```
@BindingAdapter (value = {"custom:holder", "custom:holderAttrChanged"}, requireAll = false)
public static void setHolder(Spinner spinner, Gender gender, final InverseBindingListener listener) {
    // setup spinner content
    spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(spinner.getContext(), R.layout.gender_spinner_item, Gender.values()));

    // setup listener of notifications to @InverseBindingAdapter
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            listener.onChange();
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            listener.onChange();
        }
    });
}
```

where *gender_spinner_item* - it's can be layout with one `TextView`.

Implementation of `@InverseBindingAdapter`:

```
@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "custom:holder", event = "custom:holderAttrChanged")
public static Gender getHolder(Spinner spinner) {
    return (Gender) spinner.getSelectedItem();
}
```

#### Usage:

Layout example:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable name="user" type="com.example.User"/>
    </data>

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        custom:holder="@={user.gender}" />

</layout>
```

Binding instance of `User`:

```
binder= DataBindingUtil.bind(getView());
binder.setUser(user);
```

Comment: This won't work: Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the getter for attribute 'custom:holder' with value type Gender

Comment: @Manza, I suggest to use `Spinner` instead of `EditText`. Check my answer

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it's much clear now, wondering if there is a way to use edit text

Comment: Of course @Manza . You can use `EditText` instead of `Spinner`. Note, any way you need to notify `InverseBindingListener` for reverce data flow.

Comment: Alright, I've replaced spinner with edit text and added the inverse listener in a textwatcher and I have the desired result. Thank you